# Inserting chart in detail section of a report in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, charts

I have a table with sleep data, including start date, minutes of sleep, minutes of deep sleep, minutes of light sleep, minutes of REM sleep and other fields.

I would like to present the REM, light and deep sleep data in a pie chart within a report so it is a lot more visual than plain number you need to analyze.  My report so far is grouped by start date, with a groupe header, a detail section and a group footer.  I can get a standard bar chart to work with this SQL statement but don't know what to do do have displayed as a pie chart instead:

SELECT qryDonneesSommeil.[Heure de début], Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Eveil) AS SommeDeEveil, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Paradoxal) AS SommeDeParadoxal, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Leger) AS SommeDeLeger, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Profond) AS SommeDeProfond
FROM qryDonneesSommeil
GROUP BY qryDonneesSommeil.[Heure de début];

Comment: I have no problem with chart in detail section. What does "can't get it to work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? What have you tried? Edit question to provide sample data as text table. Maybe post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I only get one field on the chart.  Maybe it's just in deciding what to put on the chart? Here is some sample data.  What I would like on the chart is " Paradoxal", "Leger" and "Profond" for each "heure debut".  Not sure what to pick as fields in the chart.  Sample data: 

Heure de début Heure de fin MinSommeil NbReveil Paradoxal Leger Profond

2022-01-30 00:38:00 2022-01-30 09:52:00 480 22 114 259 107

2022-01-28 23:04:00 2022-01-29 09:44:00 563 29 124 376 63

2022-01-27 19:51:00 2022-01-28 10:01:00 718 33 129 481 108

2022-01-26 23:20:00 2022-01-27 09:00:00 514 18 169 210 135

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as a text table. Also the attempted chart RowSource SQL statement and issue encountered.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-chart-on-a-form-or-report-1a463106-65d0-4dbb-9d66-4ecb737ea7f7

Comment: I can get a standard bar chart to work with this SQL statement but don't know what to do do have displayed as a pie chart instead:    SELECT qryDonneesSommeil.[Heure de début], Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Eveil) AS SommeDeEveil, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Paradoxal) AS SommeDeParadoxal, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Leger) AS SommeDeLeger, Sum(qryDonneesSommeil.Profond) AS SommeDeProfond
FROM qryDonneesSommeil
GROUP BY qryDonneesSommeil.[Heure de début];

Comment: This critical information should be edited into question, not scattered in comments where it's harder to read and reader might miss.